# Product manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have a question on the product of two manifolds. I have $M, N$ two real manifolds (with a smooth differentiable structure), with $\partial M=0$. I have showed that $M\times N$ has a natural induced real smooth differentiable structure, by costructing an atlas for $M\times N$ using an atlas of $M$ and an atlas of $N$. But I have the following questions.

- Why I have to assume that $\partial M=0$?
- What goes wrong if both manifolds have a boundary? For example, let's take $[0,1) \times [0,1)$.

My professor says that there no exist a local homeomorphism and so this is not a manifolds with boundary. But how I can show it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: local homeomorpshim to $\mathbb{R}^2_+$, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand why $M \times N$ is naturally a smooth manifold when $M$ and $N$ are manifolds without boundary, then the only thing you need to worry about is the specific boundary issue.

Can you properly show that if $x \in M$ where $M$ has no boundary and $y$ is a boundary point of $N$, then $(x,y)$ is a boundary point of $M \times N$ (in other words has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a Euclidean half-space) ?

If so, you should see why $(x,y)$ does not have a "suitable" neighborhood (diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space or half-space) when $x$ and $y$ are both boundary points. In your example, see what a neighborhood of the point $(0,0)$ looks like (it's a "corner").

Edit: Okay, I'll edit to give some more details (see comments). Say $x\in \partial M$ and $y \in \partial N$. Using charts, $(x,y)$ has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a Euclidean quarter-space, i.e. to $Q = \{x = (x_1, \dots, x_p) \in \mathbb{R}^p,~x_{p-1}\geqslant 0 \textrm{ and } x_{p}\geqslant 0\}$. The question is: why is this not acceptable?

- It's pretty clear that $Q$ is not diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space.
- Why is $Q$ not diffeomorphic to a Euclidean half-space? I think it's also pretty clear intuitively. Let me suggest a proof: Suppose there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi : Q \to H$ where $H = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^p, ~ x_p \geqslant 0\}$. By definition of the differentiability of such a map, $\varphi$ extends to a diffenrentiable map $\tilde{\varphi} : U \to V$ where $U$ and $V$ are neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^p$. It should be clear that $\varphi$ sends $\partial Q$ to $\partial H$. In particular it is not hard to derive that the linear map $D\tilde{\varphi}(0) : \mathbb{R}^p \to  \mathbb{R}^p$ must send both hyperplanes $\{x_{p-1}=0\}$ and $\{x_p = 0\}$ to the hyperplane $\{x_p = 0\}$. Since $D\tilde{\varphi}(0)$ is invertible, this is not possible.

Comment: Could you be more "pratical"? I'm a student, and I'm learning this subject...Sure I don't know everything..How I can show that if x is a boundary point (x,y) is a boundary point of $M \times N$?  In my example a neighborhood of the point (0,0) looks like a octant..right? and why it isn't home. to the Euclidean half space?

Comment: sorry quarter circle

Comment: In this case, the chart must be a diffeomorpshim, because i have put on the manifolds a differentiable structure...

Comment: Well, as always you should go back to the definitions: $M$ is a manifold and $x\in M$ so there exists a chart... and $y \in \partial N$ so there exists a chart... How can you make a chart around $(x,y)$ using the two?

Comment: This is obvius. An atlas is given by the combination of the two atlas. Is naturally defined. In example $A=\{(U_a\times V_b, \varphi_a \times \psi_b) \}$, where $\{(U_a, \varphi_a \}$ is atlas for M. Right?

Comment: maybe the right question at this step is: why a quarter circle isn't diffeomorphic to the half-space? i know that boundary point have to go in boundary point. In (0,0) i have two ortogonal vector that goes to tangent vector...but how i can argue that this couldn't be a diffeo?

Comment: Please see edited answer.

Comment: @andreasvr Just to add something more "visual" to this answer to help your intuition: try to think to the example $M=N=[0,1]$. Their product is the square, which has "corner" points and thus is not a smooth manifold.

Comment: Dφ~(0):Rp→Rp ??? the differential in a point doesn't send R^p in R^p...

Comment: @Daniel Intuitively I'm agree that a corner point make impossible that a diffeo between that space can't exist. I want to know WHY it can't exist. Mathematics is not only intuition...

Comment: "Dφ~(0):Rp→Rp ??? the differential in a point doesn't send R^p in R^p..."
Yes it does, what is the problem? The differential at some point of a map between open sets in $\mathbb{R}^p$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^p$